# Golang Custom Unmarshal XML

Tags: xml, go

I have been trying to write a custom Unmarshal to deal with some XML code.

I know that you can write a custom unmarshal method to deal with an individual field within a struct, however I was trying to write one on the whole struct:

```
type LowestPricedPricedOffers struct {
ASIN   string `xml:"GetLowestPricedOffersForASINResult>Identifier>ASIN"`
TimeOfOfferChange string  `xml:"GetLowestPricedOffersForASINResult>Identifier>TimeOfOfferChange"`
TotalOfferCount int   `xml:"GetLowestPricedOffersForASINResult>Summary>TotalOfferCount"`
ListPrice         float32 `xml:"GetLowestPricedOffersForASINResult>Summary>ListPrice>Amount"`
LowestNew         float32 //lowest new landed price
LowestUsed        float32 //lowest used landed price
OfferCount        map[string]map[string]int
CurrencyCode      string //currency code taken from LowestPrices
NumberOfOffers    []struct {
    OfferCount         string `xml:",innerxml"` //Will not work with int
    Condition          string `xml:"condition,attr"`
    FulfillmentChannel string `xml:"fulfillmentChannel,attr"`
} `xml:"GetLowestPricedOffersForASINResult>Summary>NumberOfOffers>OfferCount"`
LowestPrices []struct {
    Condition          string         `xml:"condition,attr"`
    FulfillmentChannel string         `xml:"fulfillmentChannel,attr"`
    LandedPrice        float32Unmarsh `xml:"LandedPrice>Amount"`
    ListingPrice       float32        `xml:"ListingPrice>Amount"`
    Shipping           float32        `xml:"Shipping>Amount"`
    CurrencyCode       string         `xml:"LandedPrice>CurrencyCode"`
} `xml:"GetLowestPricedOffersForASINResult>Summary>LowestPrices>LowestPrice"`
}


func (n *LowestPricedPricedOffers) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start    xml.StartElement) error {
for {
    t, err := d.Token()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }

    switch tt := t.(type) {
    case xml.StartElement:
        var value int
        if tt.Name.Local == "OfferCount" {
            d.DecodeElement(&value, &start)
            var condition string
            var fullfillmentChannel string
            for _, x := range tt.Attr {
                //fmt.Println(x.Name.Local, x.Value)
                if x.Name.Local == "condition" {
                    condition = x.Value
                    fmt.Println(condition)

                } else {
                    fullfillmentChannel = x.Value
                }

            }
            if n.OfferCount == nil {
                n.OfferCount = make(map[string]map[string]int)
                n.OfferCount[condition] = make(map[string]int)
                n.OfferCount[condition][fullfillmentChannel] = value

            } else {
                if n.OfferCount[condition] == nil {
                    n.OfferCount[condition] = make(map[string]int)
                }
                n.OfferCount[condition][fullfillmentChannel] = value
            }

        } else if tt.Name.Local == "ASIN" {
            d.DecodeElement(&n.ASIN, &start)
        }

        // More else if's to deal with rest of XML

    }
}
return nil
}
```

This seems to work in that I can control how my struct is populated, e.g in generating the map for 'OfferCount'.  With my generalized approach, I then need to manually populate the rest of the struct using e.g

```
} else if tt.Name.Local == "ASIN" {
        d.DecodeElement(&n.ASIN, &start)
    }
```

Which I would have to do for all the elements in the XML, having to specify the struct field for each element.  Is there a way using my approach that I can override for certain elements but just auto-populate the rest utilizing the tags in the struct as per a standard unmarshal without generating individual types for struct fields?

I have posted the full code  on the [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ewHfN6LDIOI) :

I hope this makes some sense.

I have updated my approach and question, to use custom types and custom unmarshalling on them.

The main struct has been updated as follows:

```
type LowestPricedPricedOffers struct {

Error AmazonError `xml:"Error"`
All   struct {

        /*The only way I found to retrieve 'status' from the GetLowestPricedOffersForASINResult element was to wrap in the struct 'All'.
        This is the only reason the All struct exists.  Ideally would like to remove*/
        Status            string     `xml:"status,attr"` 

    ASIN              string     `xml:"Identifier>ASIN"`
    ItemCondition     string     `xml:"Identifier>ItemCondition"`
    TimeOfOfferChange string     `xml:"Identifier>TimeOfOfferChange"`
    TotalOfferCount   int        `xml:"Summary>TotalOfferCount"`
    ListPrice         float32    `xml:"Summary>ListPrice>Amount"`
    OfferCount        offerCount `xml:"Summary>NumberOfOffers"`

    //Want to take Currency code from LowestPrices below but cannot think of a way to achieve this against the lowestPrices type
    //CurrencyCode         string               `xml:"CurrencyCode"` 

    BuyBoxPrices         buyBoxPrices         `xml:"Summary>BuyBoxPrices"`
    LowestPrices         lowestPrices         `xml:"Summary>LowestPrices"`
    BuyBoxEligibleOffers buyBoxEligibleOffers `xml:"Summary>BuyBoxEligibleOffers"`

    Offers []struct {
        SubCondition                 string  `xml:"SubCondition"`
        SellerPositiveFeedbackRating float32 `xml:"SellerFeedbackRating>SellerPositiveFeedbackRating"`
        FeedbackCount                int     `xml:"SellerFeedbackRating>FeedbackCount"`
        ShippingTime                 struct {
            MinimumHours     int    `xml:"minimumHours,attr"`
            MaximumHours     int    `xml:"maximumHours,attr"`
            AvailabilityType string `xml:"availabilityType,attr"`
        }
        ListingPrice        float32 `xml:"ListingPrice>Amount"`
        Shipping            float32 `xml:"Shipping>Amount"`
        ShipsFrom           string  `xml:"ShipsFrom>Country"`
        IsFulfilledByAmazon bool    `xml:"IsFulfilledByAmazon"`
        IsBuyBoxWinner      bool    `xml:"IsBuyBoxWinner"`
        IsFeaturedMerchant  bool    `xml:"IsFeaturedMerchant"` //true if the seller of the item is eligible to win the Buy Box.
    } `xml:"Offers>Offer"`
} `xml:"GetLowestPricedOffersForASINResult"`
```

}

It includes the 'All' struct which seemed to be the only way to get the unmarshalling of 'status' from the GetLowestPricedOffersForASINResult element.  Ideally I would like to get rid of this wrapper struct, but I am not sure that this is possible.

Some of the custom types are maps, to allow for easy retrieval of data:

```
type offerCount map[string]map[string]int

func (m *offerCount) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {

var content map[string]map[string]int
for {
    t, err := d.Token()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    switch tt := t.(type) {
    case xml.StartElement:
        var value int
        if tt.Name.Local == "OfferCount" {
            d.DecodeElement(&value, &start)
            var condition string
            var fullfillmentChannel string
            for _, x := range tt.Attr {

                if x.Name.Local == "condition" {
                    condition = x.Value

                } else {
                    fullfillmentChannel = x.Value

                }

            }

            if content == nil {
                content = make(map[string]map[string]int)
                content[condition] = make(map[string]int)
                content[condition][fullfillmentChannel] = value

            } else {
                if content[condition] == nil {
                    content[condition] = make(map[string]int)
                }
                content[condition][fullfillmentChannel] = value
            }


        }
    }
    *m = offerCount(content)
}
return nil

}
```

I am also trying to work out how to set  CurrencyCode via the lowestPrices  type, not sure if that is possible?

The full updated code is on the [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MPqO1Z2JGHH) for general comment or advice.

Comment: If you define `UnmarshalXML` on the type of a nested field, that nested field will be handled by that UnmarshalXML method. Any fields without an `UnmarshalXML` method will be handled by the default behavior. E.g. `OfferCount` could be a custom `type string` with an `UnmarshalXML` defined on it. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking at that way round at the moment, and will post back when I have something working.